# How can Redirect passes the value in Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, request, response

I am very new to Spring Framework and web develop field.

I was surprised that Spring can add attributes in its redirect response that goes to client side.

As far as I know, if a server gives a response that let client do redirect, then another request is made by client and contained values from previous request or response are gone.

But clearly it doesn't in Spring. How can this happen?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to send parameters with redirection in spring.

1.Parameters will be visible in URL.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
    public String update(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
            uiModel.addAttribute("parameter1", "value1");
            uiModel.addAttribute("parameter2", "value2");
            return "redirect:/" + "redirectionURL";
    }
```

2.Parameters will be hidden in URL.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = "text/html")
public String update(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,  RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("parameter1", "value1");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("parameter2", "value2");
        return "redirect:/" + "redirectionURL";
}
```